# how can I expire tokens after 1 minute?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to expire tokens after its creation with a max duration of 1 minute to meet security requirements. my function looks like this, but I don't think is doing it the right way, and I Would like to know what is the best way to expire the token after 1 minute? I am using the technique of diffing two times. the following function works under `models.py`

```
def is_token_expired(self):
    if self.token == None:
        return False
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    timediff = now - self.created_at
    if timediff.seconds / 60 - 1 > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: how about using django cache with timeout specified  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#basic-usage

Comment: how can I expire it after 1 minute in models?

Comment: save the token in cache, with timeout=60 when model is created. After that, when you get None with the token key, then it means token should have been expired...

Answer (score 3):

I think the elegant way to archive your goal is leveraging [django cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#basic-usage).

Sample code:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
   ...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.pk:
           # save the token when record created
           cache.set('token_key', '<Your token>', timeout=60)
       super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   @property
   def is_token_expired(self):
       # check if the token expired
       return cache.get('token_key') is None

   @property
   def token(self):
       # get token
       return cache.get('token_key')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `@property` in your model:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class Foo(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def is_expired(self):
        if datetime.now > (self.creation_date + timedelta(minutes=1)):
            return True
        return False
```

you can change `timedelta(minutes=1)` to amount that your token is valid.
and use it in your code like this:

```
if your_instance.is_expired == True:
    # do something
```

You can also use [Django builtin cache system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache) (that Enix mentioned) as a better approach.